# SQL Server 2008 Upgrade

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Is it possible to upgrade SQL Server 2008 Enterprise Evaluation to Developer Version Or Express?

I we have some old Account software that uses SQL and the Tech that Migrated the Software used the Enterprise Evaluation Copy (Now Expired) and not the Express (Even though it would have been OK for this application).

We only need to use the software until the end on Jan 2018 so i wanted the most cost effective way of getting it back online.

I have tried an Edition upgrade to Express but it does not work the Upgrade wizard works but the SQL Server service with not start.  Getting an Error 17051 which seems to lead to Trial Expired.

I can get hold of a Developer licence at a responsible price but wanted to Know if that would work prior to Purchase.

If anybody has had a similar problem would appreciate any help!

Comment: If your database doesn't include any enterprise-specific features just back up the database (or detach), uninstall enterprise, install express, and restore the database (or reattach).

Comment: You can't "upgrade" to Express and I'm surprised the upgrade wizard allows this (it didn't install a new instance, by any chance?) Upgrading to either Enterprise or Developer with a valid product key should work. If you don't want to shell out for a license, you can always install a new instance and attach the database files. You will lose server logins, though, so you'd need an easy way to recreate those. (Database users will remain intact.)